# Efficient multiplication

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

I have written some code to multiply really long numbers. Was wondering if there are more efficient ways to do this?

Here's how I've done it for now. Basically implemented the typical 'Long multiplication' technique.

```
    internal enum Digit
    {
        Zero = 0,
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        Five,
        Six,
        Seven,
        Eight,
        Nine
    }

    public class NumbersWhiz
    {
        public string Add(string Augend, string Addend)
        {
            string longerNum = (Augend.Length > Addend.Length == true) ? Augend : Addend;
            string shorterNum = (Addend.Length < Augend.Length == true) ? Addend : Augend;

            int longerLen = (Augend.Length > Addend.Length == true) ? Augend.Length : Addend.Length;
            int shorterLen = (Addend.Length < Augend.Length == true) ? Addend.Length : Augend.Length;

            //Pad the shorter number initially with zeros to match length of longer number
            int deltaLen = longerLen - shorterLen;
            string numTwoZeroed = new String('0', deltaLen);
            string numTwo = numTwoZeroed.Insert(deltaLen, shorterNum);
            string numOne = longerNum;

            string result = new String('0', longerLen);
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(result);

            bool carryForward = false;
            for (int index = longerLen; index > 0; index--)
            {
                int augend = Convert.ToInt32(numOne.Substring(index - 1, 1));
                int addend = Convert.ToInt32(numTwo.Substring(index - 1, 1));

                int sum = (carryForward == true) ? 1 : 0;
                sum = sum + augend + addend;
                carryForward = ((sum > 9) == true) ? true : false;
                int reminder = sum % 10;
                resultBuilder[index - 1] = Convert.ToChar(reminder.ToString());
            }

            if(carryForward)
                resultBuilder.Insert(0, '1');

            return resultBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public string Multiply(string Multiplicand, string Multiplier)
        {
            int resultLen = Multiplicand.Length + Multiplier.Length;
            string totalSum = new String('0', resultLen);
            for (int index = Multiplier.Length; index > 0; index--)
            {
                int multiplierDigit = Convert.ToInt32(Multiplier.Substring(index - 1, 1));

                string product = Multiply(Multiplicand, (Digit)multiplierDigit);
                product += new String('0', Multiplier.Length - index);
                totalSum = Add(totalSum, product);
            }
            return totalSum;
        }

        string Multiply(string Multiplicand, Digit MultiplierDigit)
        {
            int multiplier = (int)MultiplierDigit;
            if (multiplier == 0)
                return "0";

            int carry = 0;
            bool carryForward = false;
            int len = Multiplicand.Length;

            int productLen = len + 1;
            string result = new String('0', productLen);
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(result);

            for (int index = len; index > 0; index--)
            {
                int multiplicandDigit = Convert.ToInt32(Multiplicand.Substring(index - 1, 1));

                int product = (multiplicandDigit * multiplier) + carry;
                carryForward = ((product > 9) == true) ? true : false;
                int reminder = product % 10;
                carry = (product - reminder) / 10;
                resultBuilder[index] = Convert.ToChar(reminder.ToString());
            }

            if (carryForward)
                resultBuilder[0] = Convert.ToChar(carry.ToString());

            return resultBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) struct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Well this is an interview question I was asked recently. So if I have 2 numbers of length like 100000 represented as strings, how do i add/subtract/multiply/divide. So its more of a programming problem. :)

Comment: Okay, but why not use already implemented functionality of the .NET?

Comment: For add/subtract, the answer is easy: manipulate the string representations. With legions of digits, multiply/divide is a math/algorithm problem (with the option to operate base 10^9 or 10^19 to avoid spending more time on the conversion to string than on the operation itself).

Answer (score 3):

Yes--this is a digit-by-digit operation.

You have a couple of obvious options for doing things faster. One is a binary operation, where you treat one of the numbers as the sum of powers of two, and the result also as the sum of the partial results you get by multiplying by those powers of two.

For example, let's do 17 x 11 (which should give us 181, I believe).

So, let's think of 17 as powers of 2. It's 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> (i.e., 1 + 16). So we can take 11 * 1 + 11 * 16. We can do each of these multiplications with a shift, so it's 11<<0 + 11<<4.

Another way to look at things (that leads to a somewhat different way of doing things) is useful for large numbers. For the sake of argument, let's assume you can only do 4-bit operations. In this case, you can think of each number in 4-bit pieces and use the distributive property of multiplication to get a result--that is, we take each large number, and break it up into the sum of numbers, each of which represents a "slice" of the bits that make up the whole number. For example, consider something like 0x1234 * 0x4321, and (for the same of simplicity) we'll assume we're going to multiply them with a CPU that can multiply two 8-bit operands to produce a 16-bit result. So, we break each of those up into 8-bit slices:

```
(0x1200 + 0x34) * (0x4300 + 0x21)
```

Then we can use the distributive property:

```
0x1200 * 0x4300 + 0x1200 * 0x21 + 0x34 * 0x4300 + 0x34 * 0x21
```

Each of these (obviously enough) has only 8 significant bits, so we can carry out each of the operations on our 8-bit CPU. Then you basically just have to take the 4 intermediate results and add them all together. Any reasonable CPU will have a carry bit and an add-with-carry instruction you can use to handle this multiple precision operation.

Although I've shown it with 8-bit operations here, I think it's pretty obvious how this extends to (for example) 256-bit operands on a 32-bit or 64-bit CPU.

Comment: Both the ideas sound interesting. But i wasn't able to get hold of the idea of how i'd break massive (1000 digits long) numbers. Need to give this a thought. I'll do some searching and reading first.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes. There are more advanced multiplication methods.

A quick and easy way to speed up your algorithm a bit is to move from base-10 (aka decimal places) into a number system which is more appropriate for computers. working with 32 bit or 64 bit integers in base-2 will be much faster. You do more work per calculation and also get rid of all the modulo calculations.

Beyond that you could replace the (trivial) multiplication algorithm by something better. If your numbers start to get really large you can get huge speedups by moving into a different complexity region. Your algorithm has complexity O(n*m) where n and m are the number of digits of the two factors.

The Fast Fourier Transform can be used to do huge number multiplications much faster in O(n log n). Worth mentioning is the Number Theoretic Transform which is even more suited for this task.

There is a lot to learn and explore in the topic of large integer arithmetic. If you however just want to multiply numbers and don't care about how it's done I suggest to just use a tested and fast bignum library.

Comment: A link to a partial explanation: [number theoretic transform](http://www.apfloat.org/ntt.html) . and another link: [karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm)

Comment: looks like lots to explore...interesting for sure. I know what ill be doing weekends for next few weeks! 
Thanks for that.